# VSCode: page up/down preserving cursor vertical position

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode at least on Linux pressing PageUp/PageDown in the editor does not preserve the vertical line on the screen with the cursor. For example, when the cursor is on the tenth visible line, PageUp moves the cursor by one screen but then scrolls not by a full screen, but just to position the cursor on the first visual line. Thus pressing PageUp followed by PageDown changes the scroll.

Is it possible to change that so PageUp and PageDown preserve the cursor vertical position on the screen? I.e. if the cursor is on the tenths visible line, after PageUp it should stay on the tenth line. Visually PageUp should scroll exactly as Alt-PageUp but also move the cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a built-in command but I did just find an extension - Better PageUp / PageDown - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=russelldavis.better-pageup-pagedown
To its author Russell Davis, muchos gracias.